# Set data from database to Extjs grid with java

Tags: java, database, post, extjs, grid

2.0 from sencha but im newbie in front end developement ,
in Extjs I create a grid

*List.js*

```
Ext.define('Cmd.view.main.List', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype: 'mainlist',   
requires: [
  'Cmd.store.Personnel'
     ],
title: 'Integrantes del equipo',
store: {
    type: 'personnel'
},

columns: [
    { text: 'Nombre',  dataIndex: 'nombre', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Matricula', dataIndex: 'matricula', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Tipo', dataIndex: 'tipo', flex: 1 }
],listeners: {
    select: 'onItemSelected'
}});
```

and a data.Store file

*Personnel.js*

```
Ext.define('Cmd.store.Personnel', {
requires: [
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Proxy',
    'Ext.data.reader.Reader',
],
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.personnel',
autoLoad: false,
remoteSort: false,
proxy: {
    type    :   'ajax',
    method  :   'POST',
    url: '/list',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items'
    }
}});
```

I been told to send data in JSONObject with a POST method so I try to do this in java

*Test.java*

```
//I do a connection to a database and get some data
//put the data into JSONObject then
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:18080/mvnXD/mvnXD/list");
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.setEntity(params);
        httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(request.getMethod());
    // handle response here...
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        httpClient.close();
    }
```

so in general I want to store the data that I get from my database in the grid but im being unable to do it, and in general i cant find so much info for java and extjs

what i am missing ? i think it might be something obvious :/
any recomendations helps! thanks in advice

*Edit*

my JSONObject look like this

```
{"tipo":"Alumno","matricula":"1828","nombre":"Jaime Alberto Castillo"}
```

Comment: Are you able to return data from backend ? if yes please post that data too.

Comment: Hi sharma, if you mean get data in the JSONObject on java from the db, then yes (im posting a  example JSONObject ), but im afraid I dont fully understand

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1:**

If your JSON is like below:-

```
{
    "tipo": "Alumno",
    "matricula": "1828",
    "nombre": "Jaime Alberto Castillo"
}
```

Then you need to remove `rootProperty: 'items'` from you store's proxy.
And if you don't want to remove `rootProperty: 'items'` then your JSON should be like below:-

```
{
    "items": [{
        "tipo": "Alumno",
        "matricula": "1828",
        "nombre": "Jaime Alberto Castillo"
    }]
}
```

**Point 2:**

You need to call `load` method of your store as you set `autoLoad: false,` in your store.

See **[this example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ka0)**.

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RohitSharma, i change my JSONObject to the "items way" , I notice in the console of mozilla im getting a 404 error from the url declared in the data.Store,  `url: '/list' ` also I notice you change it to `url: data.json` in your example may I ask why this change? pd. data.json is aslo giving 404

Comment: forget it about the data.json, i see where it comes from haha